# Mysql query using LIKE operator return no result

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using php my admin to test my query and when I test a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM song WHERE title LIKE '%anytitle%'
```

It returns an empty result. With any title it gives me the same thing.

If i try the same thing on my other table users

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%gmail%'
```

It works and return all record containing gmail.

The table are built the same, utf8_unicode_ci and VARCHAR.

What could be the problem?

edit:

I destroyed my table and I have rebuild it.I have executed the query with just one row in the table and it worked.
I've repopulated the table and now it does not work.

I have 5029 records in the table.
Would it be a setting somewhere?

Re edit:
When I try like

```
SELECT * FROM song WHERE title LIKE '%d%'
```

It return every record where there is a d inside the title name. But if I try with more than one letter it does not work, I have no result.

I've updated mysql, I've unistalled it and installed version 5.6 instead and still the same issue.

Comment: you're forgetting the 'WHERE' clause

Comment: is the missing word `WHERE` a copying error or is that how your real code is written?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query -- works for me here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9fcde/1

Comment: Yeah it's a simple query I use everywhere but in that table I get no result. I can try to destroy the table and rebuild it...

Comment: case sensitivity perhaps?

Comment: I am using utf8_unicode_ci wich is case insensitive.

Comment: as users is plural, is song plural too in your database and you are just missing the s?

Comment: No it's not, other query using '=' operator works

Comment: Your table might be `utf8_unicode_ci` but what collation is the `title` / `email` column?

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll try to destroy it and rebuild it.

Comment: they are utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: SELECT * FROM `song` WHERE `title` LIKE '%anytitle%'. Can you try this

Comment: also if you could send some values in title. it would be better

Comment: I just tried and still the same thing, 

some title: 'And All Things Will End', 'Second Heartbeat', 'Seize the Day'